# Java reflection - Call protected class with public constructor that accepts Interface as argument

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, inner-classes, powermock

I would like to call a protected class that consists of a public constructor via reflection. Following is my code

```
final Class clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(parentClass.getClass(), 
"InnerClassName");
final Constructor constructor = Whitebox.getConstructor(clazz,AnInterface.class);
obj = constructor.newInstance(interfaceMockObject);
```

Im getting the below exception:

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException: Failed to lookup constructor with parameter types
```

I think is the problem might be since the constructor argument is an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner classes implicitly take the enclosing object as the first argument to their constructors. When using reflection you need to explicitly specify it, though:

```
final Class clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(parentClass.getClass(), "InnerClassName");
final Constructor constructor = 
     Whitebox.getConstructor(clazz, paretnClass.getClass(), AnInterface.class);
     // Here -----------------------^

statusPage = constructor.newInstance(parentClass, interfaceMockObject);
// And pass the parent instance -----^
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I forgot about adding that. But now Im getting this error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments" when doing "constructor.newInstance(interfaceMockObject)"

Comment: @user3050101 You need to pass the enclosing class to the constructor as the first argument. I've edited my answer to include that too.